# php if statement for mysql query result (check if query returned anything)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a bug.. and I'm thinking it might be because of this code:

```
$post = addslashes($post);

 $r = $conn->query("select id from Posts where post='$post'");

 if($id = $r->fetch_assoc()["id"]){
    echo 'greg!!!<br>';
 }
```

I'm just trying to echo 'greg!!!' if the query "select id from Posts where post='$post'" returns anything.  I'm finding that sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't... so not really sure.  Maybe it's a quotes issue?... but I would think that the addslashes method would take care of that

Comment: what does the error say ?

Comment: do you use here condition `if($id = $r->fetch_assoc()["id"])` i think it should `if($id == $r->fetch_assoc()["id"])` ?

Comment: not getting an error.... But the code is not running as expected.  I'm getting duplicate entries when I shouldn't be.  As to the == , I haven't predefined $id anywhere, I'm just trying to see if the query returned ANY results or if there were no matches in the database

Comment: Why you don't check with `mysqli_num_rows`, or PDO equivalent?

Comment: thanks!  mysqli_num_rows is cleaner and a little more obvious.  I think my bug was just a stupid mistake.  I was mis-ordering the things I was checking for.

Answer (score 0):

`$r->fetch_assoc()["id"]`

I think this will not work, because `$r->fetch_assoc()` is not an array yet. It should be like:

```
$post = addslashes($post);

$r = $conn->query("select id from Posts where post='$post'");
$fetch = $r->fetch_assoc();
if($id = $fetch["id"]){
   echo 'greg!!!<br>';
}
```

And it will get in `if` if SQL query returns anything. You can always check your array with f.ex.:

```
print_r($fetch);
```

Or use `$r->num_rows` to count how many rows have been returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rowCount()`if PDO, or `num_rows` if MySQLi to check if there were any rows returned.

```
// PDO
if($r->rowCount() > 0){echo "greg";}

// MySQLi
if($r->num_rows > 0){echo "greg";}
```